# Should columns generated during ETL be added to schema?

Tags: apache-spark

I read a CSV then do some transformations, adding a few columns using `.withColumn(...)`, then write to parquet format. Would it help performance to add those added columns to the read() schema?

Comment: You mean the schema of your resulting table in parquet? By helping performance, I assume you refer to the overhead added by the extra columns when reading the parquet file _after_ the ETL? If so - parquet is a columnar file format - it allows you to read specific columns without loading the entire content of a file. Spark can benefit from it if you choose to work on a strict sub-set of columns available in the file's schema.

Comment: How would that "Would it help performance to add those added columns to the read() schema?" influence reading part since it touches CSVs while writing part is about parquet? Please elaborate on these by editing your question and adding more information. Thanks.